# SharePoint 2013 document library add a "new folder" button

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

i would like to add a "new folder" button to a document library page, so that, users won't have to go to the ribbon for the option. i used the following code.

```
<a href="javascript:OpenPopUpPageWithTitle('
    https://teams.connect.te.com/sites/PCINDIRECT/testing add folder/Forms/Upload.aspx?RootFolder=&Type=1&IsDlg=1′,RefreshOnDialogClose,null,null,'testing add folder');">New Folder</a>
```

the following is the original code

```
<a href=”javascript:OpenPopUpPageWithTitle(‘</site/library>/Forms/Upload.aspx?RootFolder=&Type=1&IsDlg=1′,RefreshOnDialogClose,null,null,'<Title>’);” >New Folder</a>
```

but it is not working for me. can you please advise how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This approach is not recommended. Use REST,JSOM to achieve it

REST : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841(v=office.15).aspx#bk_FolderCollectionAdd

```
var folderPath = "Library/CustomFolder"; //TODO: get library and folder name as arguments

var folderCreate = jQuery.ajax({
"url"        : _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Folders/add("+folderPath+")",
"type"       : "POST",
"headers"    : { 
                "accept"          : "application/json; odata=verbose", 
                "content-type"    : "application/json; odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest" : $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
               }
}); 

jQuery.when(folderCreate).always(function (data){
   console.log(data);
});
```